# Add Label in the middle of the line

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

i created a custom control which represents an edge of a graph. In the middle of the is the weight displayed.

[image] (Circules are vertices and the connecting line are the edges)

I made this by drawing the weight with the overriden OnRender method. But this isn't a nice solution.

There is no way to make the the weight editable for example by a textbox. So it would be great if I could add a TextBox or a ContentPresenter to the overriden OnRender method in order to make the weight editable. But I dont' know how to do this.

Anyway, this is my current state:

```
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:Edge}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:Edge}">
                <DockPanel>
                    <Line Stroke="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" 
                    X1="{Binding Mode=TwoWay,Path=PositionU.X,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type local:Edge}}}"
                    Y1="{Binding Mode=TwoWay,Path=PositionU.Y,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type local:Edge}}}"
                    X2="{Binding Mode=TwoWay,Path=PositionV.X,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type local:Edge}}}"
                    Y2="{Binding Mode=TwoWay,Path=PositionV.Y,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type local:Edge}}}" >
                    </Line>
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

CODEBehind for the control:

```
 public class Edge : Control
{
    static Edge()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Edge), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(Edge)));

    }
    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        base.OnRender(drawingContext);

        Point p = new Point((PositionV.X + PositionU.X) / 2 + 4, (PositionV.Y + PositionU.Y) / 2);

        drawingContext.DrawText(new FormattedText(Weight != null ? Weight.ToString() : "",
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, FlowDirection.LeftToRight, new Typeface(this.FontFamily.ToString()),
            this.FontSize, this.Foreground), p);

    }

    public int Weight
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(WeightProperty); }
        set { SetValue(WeightProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Weight.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty WeightProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Weight", typeof(int), typeof(Edge), new UIPropertyMetadata(0));


    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the value of the position from the correspondending U Vertex control
    /// </summary>
    public Point PositionU
    {
        get { return (Point)GetValue(PositionUProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PositionUProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for PositionU.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PositionUProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("PositionU", typeof(Point), typeof(Edge), new UIPropertyMetadata(new Point()));



    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the value of the position from the correspondending V Vertex control
    /// </summary>
    public Point PositionV
    {
        get { return (Point)GetValue(PositionVProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PositionVProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for PositionV.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PositionVProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("PositionV", typeof(Point), typeof(Edge), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));




}
```

How can I display the weight with a TextBlock/TextBox in the middle of the line?

Comment: Don't override `OnRender()` in WPF. This is not winforms. Why don't you just add the desired UI elements in the ControlTemplate?

Comment: I don't know how to add the UI Element beside the line. Also the UI Element should be placed horizontal at half of the line.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar before by using a MultiBinding and a converter.

You bind the top of the textblock, as a multibinding to the Y of the first point and the Y of the second point and use a converter to average them to a single value, then repeat for the Left = average of X's.

Something like

```
<Canvas.Left>
  <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource findCentreConverter}">
     <Binding ElementName=yourLine, Path=X1/>
     <Binding ElementName=yourLine, Path=X2/>
  </MultiBinding>
</Canvas.Left>
```

repeat for Canvas.Top

and your FindCentreConverter is something like

```
public class FindCentreMultiConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
    var point1 = (double)values[0];
    var point2 = (double)values[1];
    return (double)((point1 + point2) / 2.0d);
  }

  public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

Obviously this will put the text starting at the centre of the line, but you can modify the converter to take additional values or a parameter, such as an offset for the X/Y to avoid this. Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx for an example with a parameter .

Comment: I don't know if i understand you correctly, because the TextBlock doesn't provide a Top Dp on which I can bind. Also the Edge Control doesn' contain a canvas.

Comment: Ok, I think you need to read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745058.aspx. I believe your Edges should be *inside* a Canvas, which is the only container that provides explicit positioning. If you think about it, you are currently drawing overlapping Edges (all start at 0,0) that happen to only draw lines pushed down to their bottom right corners or (possibly because you've overriden OnRender) outside of their control bounds. I'm pretty sure this will cause you problems later.